# Laravel Nova nova_pending_field_attachments issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

After Running php artisan migrate:fresh I get a failed migration for 2022_12_19_000000_create_field_attachments_table

1   C:\xampp\htdocs\main-app\vendor\yajra\laravel-pdo-via-oci8\src\Pdo\Oci8\Statement.php:797
Yajra\Pdo\Oci8\Exceptions\Oci8Exception::("Error Code    : 955
Error Message : ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
Position      : 33
Statement     : create sequence FMISC_ADMIN_TEST.nova_pending_field_attachments minvalue 1  start with 1 increment by 1
Bindings      : []
")

2   C:\xampp\htdocs\main-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:545

Comment: I think there is a duplicate in the table name. Can you cross check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue after importing some mySql data into my local dev environment and attempting to run existing migrations.

Some Laravel fields create their own migrations to support their functionality. In my case, Laravel Nova was creating a couple of 'field attachment' tables.

The migration error occurs because the migrations in question do not have any checks for existing tables. These migrations, in my case, were located in vendor/laravel/nova/database/migrations. Adding the following in the migration file will perform a simple check and skip the migration if an existing table is found:

```
if (Schema::hasTable('nova_pending_field_attachments')) {
            return;
        }
```